# Clojure - problems with syntax for accessing gen-class from another namespace

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

It seems like lein is unpredictable in how it recompiles code. I have a gen-class file in one directory, trying to access it in another. For example, given this gen-class:

```
(ns a.Target
    (:gen-class
     :state state
     :init  init
     :constructors {[String String] []}))

(defn -init
  [m1  m2]
  [[]  (atom {"A" m1 "B" m2})])

(defn -deref
  [this]
  @(.state this))
```

And trying to access this from another namespace, reduced to trying random variations of 1, 2,3:

```
(ns b.runner
    (:require [a.Target  ] :as Target) ;1
    (:import '(a Target))              ;2
)

(compile 'a.Target) ;3
```

It seems like there is no syntax that will recognize "Target" instead of "a.Target", so there's clearly something not correct in how I'm addressing the gen-class. This is a problem because I'm trying to access our guice-injectors using annotated provider methods, and the annotation syntax doesn't seem to accept either complete or simple class specifications:

```
(definterface TargetProvider (^a.Target getTarget [this] ))
=> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: nth not supported on this type:
```

or simplified ones:

```
(definterface TargetProvider (^Target getTarget [this] ))
=> Can't find class java.lang.Target
```

Comment: You have a typo in your ns form: `(:require [a.Target :as Target])`, not `(:require [a.Target  ] :as Target)`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3):

The ns expression should be `(ns b (:import a.Target))` there's no need of using `:require` for the class to be imported. Since `ns` is macro, all symbols in `:require`, `:use` and other options are not evaluated, so there's no need to quote them. With the following `ns` declaration your `definterface` expression should work.

```
(ns b
  (:import a.Target))

(definterface TargetProvider [^a.Target getTarget []])

(->> b.TargetProvider .getMethods seq)
;= (#<Method public abstract a.Target b.TargetProvider.getTarget()>)
```

---

**EDIT**

This is the code for a proxy using the `TargetProvider` interface defined above, which I think is what you were asking for in the comments.

Note that I also modified the declaration of the interface's `getTarget` method, removing the `this` argument, since it does not actually receive a reference of the current instance. When using `proxy` there is an implicitly bound `this` local (see [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/proxy) for more information).

```
(let [x (proxy [TargetProvider] []
          (getTarget [] (Target. "x" "y")))]
  (.getTarget x))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. Hate to ask for more, but can you add an example of a proxy that uses this interface? When I add the method it doesn't seem to pick up the annotation. Trying e.g. 
( ^{Provides  {}}  ^a.Target  getTarget [this] ( ... ))

Comment: Thanks for the edit - appreciate it. However, that syntax gives:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching method found: getMethod for class
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:53) ...
Still mucking with the syntax, I'll post if I can get the damned thing to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the error you mention doesn't sound like it has something to do with the syntax. Please add the code for the whole ns that's causing the error you posted in the previous comment and we'll take it from there.